# When does an algebraically independent set "satisfy Noether normalization"?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra.
By Noether normalization, we know that there exists a finite morphism of $k$-algebras $\varphi : k[x_1, \ldots, x_d] \hookrightarrow A$, with $d = \dim A$.

I say that a tuple $u_1, \ldots, u_d$ satisfies Noether normalization, if the elements are algebraically independent over $k$, and the (injective) morphism $\varphi_\boldsymbol{u} : k[x_1, \ldots, x_d] \hookrightarrow A$, $x_i \mapsto u_i$ is a finite morphism.

My question: given a tuple $a_1, \ldots, a_d \in A$, which form an algebraically independent set over $k$, is there an easy way to see if they satisfy Noether normalization?

More generally, is there a construction, that, given $a_1, \ldots, a_d$ algebraically independent, produces $b_1, \ldots, b_d$ which satisfy Noether normalization?

Note: [Choosing the algebraic independent elements in Noether's normalization lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42275/choosing-the-algebraic-independent-elements-in-noethers-normalization-lemma) is a related question, but does not quite answer mine.